# Как объединить 2 локальные сети через openvpn

Tags: openvpn, asus, xiaomi

Всем привет! Исходные данные: 2 роутера (тплинк и асус), 2 провайдера, у тплинка статический айпи. Айпи тплинка 192.168.0.1, асуса 192.168.1.1. Запускаю опенвпн сервер на тплинке и коннекчусь к нему с асуса. Коннект встает. С асуса апишники тплинка пингуются, т.е. 192.168.0.0 для сетки за асусом доступны, но в обратном направлении ни в какую. Предполагаю, что где-то надо прописать маршруты. Но не вывожу самостоятельно. Подскажите, где и что поправить, чтобы айпишники за асусом были доступны для тплинка